# Is there a way to get GroovyMock (in Spock) accepting a GString for a String argument?

Tags: groovy, mocking, spock

Unfortunately I could not yet find any useful information about this topic.

I have some Spock tests where I need to use a `GroovyMock` instead of a `Mock` - as of it's support for mocking dynamic methods.

One of the (non-dynamic) method takes a String argument. Sometimes a GString gets passed as an argument to that method. That is working fine in the productive code as well as for a `Mock`.

However after switching to a `GroovyMock` I got a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch` exception pointing me to the following line (see example below):

```
        someClass.someMethod("foo ${1 + 1}")
```

I did already check whether some of the options available during creation of the `GroovyMock` could help. So far I tried the `verified` option - which unfortunately did not help. The other options did not even seem to bear the chance to be useful here, so I did not try to use them (and for most of them I would not even have known how to use them).

Please check the following small example for reference:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class SomeClass {
    String someMethod(String arg) {
        return arg
    }
}

class TestClass {
    SomeClass someClass

    String callMethod() {
        someClass.someMethod("foo ${1 + 1}")
    }
}

class FooSpec extends Specification {
    def 'pass String to groovyMock mocked method taking a String argument'() {
        given:
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass()
        SomeClass someClass = GroovyMock() // does not work
        // SomeClass someClass = Mock() // test works if used instead of the previous line
        testClass.someClass = someClass

        when:
        testClass.callMethod()

        then:
        1 * someClass.someMethod(_)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good catch! I can confirm this behaviour in both Spock `1.3-groovy-2.5` and `2.0-M3-groovy-3.0`. I think it would make sense to create a [Spock issue](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues) and link back to this question from there.

I have debugged into the issue and printed the stack trace before it gets "cleaned up" for test error reporting. You might want to add it to the new issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.GroovyMockMetaClass.doInvokeMethod(GroovyMockMetaClass.java:83)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.GroovyMockMetaClass.invokeMethod(GroovyMockMetaClass.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q63797837.TestClass.callMethod(FooSpec.groovy:15)
    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q63797837.TestClass$callMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q63797837.FooSpec.$spock_feature_0_0(FooSpec.groovy:28)
    ... 34 more
```

---

**Update:** One more finding: If you change the target method signature to `String someMethod(GString arg)`, the test passes with the GroovyMock. So possibly the problem is somehow connected to casting the `GString` used in `someClass.someMethod("foo ${1 + 1}")` into a `String`.

---

**Update 2020-09-16:** A couple of days ago I have created [Spock issue #1216](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1216) on your behalf because you ignored my advice to do so by yourself. The bug has been fixed already and I expect it to be available in the next 2.0 milestone release and of course also in the final release.

Comment: **Update:** [Spock issue #1216](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1216) has been fixed, see my answer update.